# Material-UI - set selected color of ListItemSecondaryAction

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, jss

I am trying to set change the color if the ListItem is selected.

The problem is that the ListItemSecondaryAction is not wrapped by the ListItem root, but by a container.

How do I apply styles to the container if the ListItem is selected?

My ListItem styles are:

```js
root: {
  borderRadius: 6,
  padding: '0.5rem 1rem',
  marginBottom: spacing(),
},
selected: {
  '&.Mui-selected': {
    fontWeight: 500,
    backgroundColor: accentColor,
    color: palette.primary.main,
    '&:hover': {
      color: palette.primary.main,
      backgroundColor: accentColor,
    },
  },
},
```

My JSX is:

```
<ListItem style={{ ...style }} classes={ListItemClasses} selected={selected} button>
  <ListItemIcon className={selected ? classes.ListItemIconSelected : classes.ListItemIcon}>
    {icon}
  </ListItemIcon>
  <ListItemText>{text}</ListItemText>
  <ListItemSecondaryAction>
    <IconButton color="inherit" edge="end">
      <Settings />
    </IconButton>
   </ListItemSecondaryAction>
</ListItem>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright nevermind...

I could just have done this:

```
ListItemSecondarySelected: {
  color: palette.primary.main,
},
```

```
<ListItem style={{ ...style }} classes={ListItemClasses} selected={selected} button>
  <ListItemIcon className={selected ? classes.ListItemIconSelected : classes.ListItemIcon}>
    {icon}
  </ListItemIcon>
  <ListItemText>{text}</ListItemText>
  {canAccessSettings && (
    <ListItemSecondaryAction className={selected ? classes.ListItemSecondarySelected : ''}>
    <IconButton color="inherit" edge="end">
      <Settings />
    </IconButton>
  </ListItemSecondaryAction>
  )}
</ListItem>
```